# Weird generic return type with T in angled brackets

Tags: java, generics

Browsing through [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/Files.java) libraries I saw this weird signature on the `readLines` method of the `Files` class:

```
public static <T> T readLines(File file,
                          Charset charset,
                          LineProcessor<T> callback)
```

I know a little bit about generics in Java, but this baffled me.

What does the double `T` mean here? And why is the first one in angled brackets?

After some answers, I am still not clear as to why I should use a `T` inside the brackets. Why for example can't it just be:

```
 public static <> T readLines()
```

or

```
 public static <K> T readLines()
```

Or does the Java syntax dictate that the *same* letter must be used?

Now [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) is even wierder:

```
static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
```

how can a method have a generic-return type and be `void`?

Comment: The T in angle brackets is NOT the return type; it's the type parameter for the method.

Comment: Note that if there was no <T> in the above signatures, the compiler would naturally expect to find "class T { ... }" defined somewhere. Something has to inform the compiler that you'd like there to be a *type parameter* called T.  And this is the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > I am still not clear as to why I should use a T inside the brackets. Why for example can't it just be:
>
> ```
>  public static <> T readLines()
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>  public static <K> T readLines()
> ```
>
> Or does the java syntax dictate that the SAME letter must be used?

The `<T>` or `<K>` is the type parameter. If you write `<K> T`, then the T isn't a type parameter - rather, you're using the specific `class T`. This won't work if you don't have a class that's literally named `T` in scope.

> Now this is even wierder:
>
> ```
> static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
> ```
>
> how can a method have a generic-return type and be void?

It doesn't; the `<T>` is not a "generic return type", it's just the type parameter to the method. You're saying that the method is generic, and `T` is the type parameter. The return type of the method is `void`.

Comment: This is the sentence I was looking for: "You're saying that the method is generic, and T is the type parameter." Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It's a *generic method* -- the `T` is called a *type parameter*, and can represent any type.  So if I have a method with this signature:

```
public <T> T foo(T[] bar)
```

I can call it on any array, and it will return a single object of the same type.  If I pass it a String array, I'll get back a String, and so on.  More information [in the Sun tutorials for "generic methods".](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

**Edit:**  In answer to your updated question, bear in mind that the first `<T>` *isn't* part of the return type: it's just an indicator that `T` is a type parameter.  So look at the example you quoted:

```
static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c)
```

That just means that `fromArrayToCollection` will accept any array and any collection, *but* that they must be an array and collection of the same type.  So you can pass in a `String[]` and a `Collection<String>`, or an `Integer[]` and a `Collection<Integer>`, but not a `String[]` and a `Collection<Integer>`.  No matter what type you put in for `T`, the method returns nothing.

Answer (score 7):

The first `T` inside the angle brackets mean that the method itself is generic. The second `T` is the return type. `T` can be any type within its bounds. In this case, `T` has no bounds.

T will be determined at the call site, and in this case, inferred from the `LineProcessor<T>` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of being generic at class level only the method readLines uses generics.

- The first `<T>` declares the generic types used by the method
- The following `T` is the return type.

The first one uses the same syntax as a generic class to declare the generic types. Instead you could write

```
class Generic <T> 
{
public static T readLines(File file,
                          Charset charset,
                          LineProcessor<T> callback)
}
```

This however would make all instances of the class generic.

Extended Example:

```
public static <ElementType,ListType extends List<ElementType>> ListType add(ListType list,ElementType elem)
{
   list.add(elem);
   return list;
}
ArrayList<String> al = add(add(new ArrayList<String>(),"Hello"),"World");
```

The method adds a given Element to a List and returns the List.
The method uses two generic Types one for the elements of the list and one for the list itself.
**The names used are nothing special, using a `T` for a generic type is like using `i` for an integer.**

- `ElementType` is the name used for the generic Type of the elements (any valid variable name / identifier could be used)
- `ListType` is the name for the generic list Type, the classes used have to extend/implement `List` for the `ElementType`.

The example calls the method with:

- `ElementType` = `String`
- `ListType` = `ArrayList<String>`

which would result in
`public static ArrayList<String> add(ArrayList<String> list, String elem)`

Bloat end :-)

Comment: Thanks, this makes it clearer... but why do i have to use a letter "T" inside the brackets as opposed to, say, letter "K" or "B" or none at all (i.e. just empty brackets).

Comment: The letter T is only a name, the names between < and > only declare names for the generic types used. You could declare a method with 3 generic types like this public static <TypeA,AnOtherType,ExtraType> ExtraType someMethod(TypeA var1,AnOtherTypeB var2, ExtraType var3).

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic method.

Actually there are three Ts, the third on `LineProcessor<T>` specifies T when you use the method.